# Rename remote file downloaded from another server to client using PHP

Tags: php, file-io, header, download

I have the link to the file i want to download but the file is saved with a weird name like "450033"
without any file extension.

The only code that worked for me(partially) was this

```
<?php
$file_path = "url to file";
ob_start();
header("Content-Type: application/zip");
header('Content-Length: '.remotefilesize($file_path) );
header("Content-disposition: attachment; filename=thefile.zip");
$chunksize = 128 * 1024; // how many bytes per chunk (128 KB)
$size = filesize($file_path);
if ($size > $chunksize){
    $handle = fopen($file_path, 'rb');
    $buffer = '';
    while (!feof($handle)) {
      buffer = fread($handle, $chunksize);
      echo $buffer;
      flush();
      sleep(1);
    }
    fclose($handle);
 }else{
    readfile($file_path);
 }
?>
```

The above code downloads the file but does not show any progress bar, the page actually just keeps loading until the file is downloaded.
Is there anyway to rename the file and show the progress bar too?

Comment: You should download the file via an Ajax request and use a progress handler to update the progress bar while the file is being downloaded.

Comment: @Alex  thnx!
Let's see if i can do what you are saying.
Newbie here :)

Comment: We've all been there, unfortunately on my phone atm else I could be of more help!

Comment: @Alex i think i didnt put the question correctly.
What i was trying to ask was , 
I download the file from another server and i am saving it on the client side plus i wish to change the name of the downloaded file and let the browser show the download progress.
[Image](http://imgur.com/tlTbGIz)